# Spring Integration - Two permanents connections with RoundRobin and Failover

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-dsl

It's possible (using the existing components of Spring-Integration) to have two permanents connections to two differents TCP Servers, that allow us to make a round-robin between the connections, and on the case of fails, try with the other connection?

We are using the FailoverClientConnectionFactory, with two TcpNioClientConnectionFactory (each one to connect to a different server).
But that means that our application it's working at 50%. Because it's using a shared connection, and we could make a round-robin to use the two TCP servers.

I'm struggling with this scenario.
We are considered to make our own CustomRoundRobinFailoverConnectionFactory or use the IntegrationFlow library, but maybe it's a better way to do it.

---

**EDIT 1** - SOLUTION

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="outboundChannel")
public MessageHandler outboundGatewayOne() {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(failoverClientConnectionFactoryOne);
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="outboundChannel")
public MessageHandler outboundGatewayTwo() {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(failoverClientConnectionFactoryTwo);
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel outboundChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel="outboundChannel")
public interface TcpClientGateway {
    byte[] send(byte[] message);
}
```

So this is working. But now, I want to avoid having the two outboundGateways hardcoded. It's a better way to do it?
I tried using the same outboundGateway for the two connection factories but doesn't work.

- **Answer**: No, you can't. We need to have the two OutboundGateways as consumers on DirectChannel to get the round-robin distribution. Each gateway is a consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is to configure 2 outbound endpoints with 2 `FailoverClientConnectionFactory` instances.

Change the order of the target factories.

```
FCCF1 -> server1, server2
FCCF2 -> server2, server1
```

Use the same channel (`DirectChannel`) as the input channel to the endpoints.

Messages sent to that channel will be round-robin distributed to the two endpoints.

Comment: Thanks, Gary! I'll be trying that way

Comment: You should also take a look at the `refreshSharedInterval` and `closeOnRefresh` properties, so you can fail-back when a server comes back on line.

Comment: Thanks! I succeed on make works the DirectChannel with the round-robbin. Now I have the issue in the **EDIT 1**. Is there another way to do it? I'm trying to do it reading the documentation but I'm not finding how.

Comment: No; you can't do that; the fact that we have two consumers on `outboundChannel` is why we get round robin distribution. Each gateway is a consumer.

Comment: Yep, and those gateways need to be a @Bean, so it's not another way. But it's working, so thanks for the help!